# Android Swipe Tab customize the Tab Indicator color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to change the tab indicator color (see image below):

[image]

Even if I follow the following official tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs I still can't make it work.

The application compile version is: *compileSdkVersion 22*

The application theme is: *Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar*

**...res/values/styles.xml** (theme customizations file)

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorDark</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>

<color name="colorDark">#ff9800</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">#ffc107</color>
<color name="happy">#ffeb3b</color>
<color name="normal">#fff176</color>
<color name="sad">#fff59d</color>
</resources>
```

**...res/drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_example" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_example" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_example" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true" />

<!--    Focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

Can't figure out where is the problem, everything compiles without errors and the code follows step by step the official documentation. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [PagerSliderTabStrip](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip) in some of my projects. It's easy to set up and use.

gradle file:

```
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
```

layout.xml file:

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Activity.java:

```
// Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

// Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

To change the color of the selector, use:

```
PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.pstsIndicatorColor(yourColor);
```

Comment: Thx. It is possible that there isn't a simple and working solution? I mean ... It's just an indicator color...

Comment: My experience extends only to using this lib, which I recommend for you in the future! @P.Alex

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution, but as you can see here https://i.imgur.com/OI0o1Aa.png I get an extra space at the top, should I disable or enable something?

Comment: Looks like you have set some padding that messes up the layout. I think it's easier if you start a new question and link it to me, including your XML and Java code for the pager setup. @P.Alex

Comment: Solved, I've removed actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); and everything works now. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily try this

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
//Use Color Resource here or directly parse color just like this
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the SlidingTabLayout Class and SlidingTabStrip style ([Something like this](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)), Then you can simply call the method of the SlidingTabLayout Class called `setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors)` the parameter is an array, but in the array you could just put only one color. So if you wanted to call the method from the SlidingTabLayout, it would look something like:

```
int[] color = {Color.Pink, Color.Red, Color.Awesome};
//It could be only one color if you want

SlidingTabLayout tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(color);
```

But you can only do this if you followed the tutorial I linked above and used his Tab implementation style.

NOTE: This is the recommended and supported way that the Material Design stuff is implemented. On more Material Design Tuts, just google with keywords "Material Design Tab Tutorial Example"

Answer (score 1):

you can change tab Indicator colour using this code :

```
    tabs = setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer(){
    @override 
    public int getIndicatorColor(int position)
    return getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    }
 )};
```

check this sample tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSaSNX5QI-E&index=27&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding all complexity I would suggest to use [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

As it is very easy to use and have lot of customization as well.By this you will be able to create sliding tabs like in google play app.